# Passing Values between User Controls and ASPX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass the value of the selected index 
in a listbox (which is an html filename) to the be a src of the iframe.

```
<iframe id="iframeID" 
        frameborder="0" 
        width="100%" 
        height="300px" 
        runat="server">
</iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementById('<%=ListBox1.ClientID %>');
var val = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;            
document.getElementById("iframeID").src =  val;
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should define `not working`?

Comment: You might want to step through the Javascript code using chrome developer tools (F12) by putting a breakpoint on the Source. (Press the Esc key whilst in the tools to bring up a console to query values)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have the `runat="server"` on the iframe, so this call

```
document.getElementById("iframeID").src =  val;
```

must also be as:

```
document.getElementById('<%=iframeID.ClientID %>').src =  val;
```

or remove the `runat="server"` from the iframe

Comment: Thank you. But it says that 'iframeID' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @AbyBendo then try to remove the `runat="server"`

Answer (score 0):

possibly:

```
var val = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
```